# Error when using parameters with SSIS in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis

I have a simple query (included below). It's used inside a loop with two parameters. It works as a charm on one server, but when I use it with another server, it fails with "Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command".

```
DECLARE @Tagnavn As varchar(250)
DECLARE @HentEnergiNiveauEfter As datetime2(7)
set @Tagnavn = ?
set @HentEnergiNiveauEfter = ?
EXEC [FDTV_PUMP_AVERAGE_CONSUMPTION_FROM_DATE] @Tagnavn ,@HentEnergiNiveauEfter
```

I've seen the workaround with putting the query in a variable, but this doesn't work for me. And I really don't understand why the above works on one server but not another :-)

The working set-up consists of:

-Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017, v15.3.3

-the stored procedure is on an SQL Server v11

The non-working set-up consists of:

-Visual Studio Community 2017 - Tools for Applications 2017, v15.7.3

-the stored procedure is on an SQL Server v10

Thanks!

Palle

Comment: Out of interest, why are you declaring variable in your SQL and then using those? Why not simply `EXEC [FDTV_PUMP_AVERAGE_CONSUMPTION_FROM_DATE] ?, ?;`?

Comment: I don't even know what `?` doing here?

Comment: the ? indicates the variable is set in the package. So did you set your variable? (where you paste your query in the dataflowtask, to the right click 'Parameters')

Comment: Larnu, I tried without the intermediate variables, but then it doesn't get the parameters. @ppijnenburg: yup, did that. The code is exactly the same on the working server, and the none-working. I had a similar problem a while ago, where I simply re-wrote the code to something else, but similar.

Comment: What are all the differences between the two servers?

Comment: @TabAlleman: I've edited my question to reflect the differences. Could it be a version thing? If yes, is it VS, SSIS or the SQL servers?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Permission problems with the server holding the stored procedure. Thanks for your input. And @Larnu: now it works without the temp. variables :-)

Thanks again,

Palle